# An app can’t load remote web content in the local context in Windows8 - Cordova App

Tags: javascript, cordova, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

My app is throwing:

> An app can’t load remote web content in the local context

error when creating the `DOM` element. I am executing the code in `MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction`

Below is the piece of code

```
 loadScript: function (a) {
    var b = document.createElement("script");
    var hellRet = b;
    MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction(function () {
        var b = hellRet;
        return b.type = "text/javascript",
        b.src = a, // **throwing the error when setting the URL http://example.com/api/v2/viz/ddddd/viz.json?callback=vizjson**
        b.async = !0, c.head || (c.head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]), setTimeout(function () {
            c.head.appendChild(b)
        }, 0), b
    });
}
```

Environment: VS 2013, Cordova 5.3.3